# Skip rows which has the same name in one column

Tags: r

So I would like to remove from my data the rows which has the same "id" (in this case it's 221 and 341)
As you see the values in other columns are different so I would like to delete duplicated rows (same id) but I still would like to keep the one of the rows.

```
>head(data)
id  Sequence    Score   variable              value
221 AAIYKLLKSHF 30.87   BiotinControl1_2    221498.368
341 EKPLFLVFHGT 42.04   BiotinControl1_2    255198.8712
330 FMIAPTGAKTF 49.67   BiotinControl1_2    1526577.651
221 FMIAPTGAKTF 40.69   BiotinControl2          429384.4861
341 GKLKGVLGYTE 39.34   BiotinTreatment1    597884.8329
196 IKKVVKAAAE  39.81   BiotinControl1_2    2277435.528
117 IKKVVKAAAE  44.86   BiotinControl1_2    1050394.325
```

so that's how should my data looks like:

```
id  Sequence    Score   variable              value
221 AAIYKLLKSHF 30.87   BiotinControl1_2    221498.368
341 EKPLFLVFHGT 42.04   BiotinControl1_2    255198.8712
330 FMIAPTGAKTF 49.67   BiotinControl1_2    1526577.651
196 IKKVVKAAAE  39.81   BiotinControl1_2    2277435.528
117 IKKVVKAAAE  44.86   BiotinControl1_2    1050394.325
```

Which function should I use to do something like that ?

Comment: What happened when you searched SO for "delete duplicated rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `duplicated`

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$id),]
   id    Sequence Score         variable     value
1 221 AAIYKLLKSHF 30.87 BiotinControl1_2  221498.4
2 341 EKPLFLVFHGT 42.04 BiotinControl1_2  255198.9
3 330 FMIAPTGAKTF 49.67 BiotinControl1_2 1526577.7
6 196  IKKVVKAAAE 39.81 BiotinControl1_2 2277435.5
7 117  IKKVVKAAAE 44.86 BiotinControl1_2 1050394.3
```